# How to populate a View with data from the Store?

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

In Sencha Touch 2, I have this code in the Controller.
Main aim is to populate a View with Data from the Store.
At the moment I use `setRecord` with no success.

Could you please point me out in the right direction with a sample of code? Thnks

```
// Load data in the model after a user is successfully authenticated
    populateViewsAfterLogIn: function (){
        var me = this;
        var storeEvents2 =  Ext.getStore('Events2');
        storeEvents2.load();
        storeEvents2.sync();

        var myDashBoardView = me.getNavigViewTimetable();
        myDashBoardView.setRecord(storeEvents2);


    },
```

Comment: I believe you should be using `set`. `setRecord` is used to change the value of a record. See [Sencha Docs](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-method-set).

Comment: I tried but it does not work, thanks for your comment

Comment: You're trying to set the record, but you pass in a Store. Try using either `myDashboardView.setStore(storeEvents2);` or get a record out of the store to use the setter you have.

Comment: guys, thanks for your help. I am using already myDashboardView.setStore(storeEvents2);  .... I would really appreciate if you could provide me a sample of code so I can Up Vote and accept your answer thanks both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So just to reiterate, I think you want to use `setStore(...)` instead of `setRecord(...)`:

```
myDashBoardView.setStore(storeEvents2);
```

Then inside your view you can access the store using: `this.getStore();` or loop through the store records this way:

```
this.getStore().each(function(item, index, length) {
  // do something with the record (item)
});
```

Good luck, let us know if it works.